# How To Maintain live website on production?

Tags: node.js, web, digital-ocean, production, react-fullstack

If I have a full-stack website hosted somewhere (digital ocean droplet for example), And I have developed new feature. How can I test it on production and how to push it to prod?

It can be a small design feature but it can also be something more complicated like adding comments to a post.

Comment: Don't test on production - test on staging instead, then once you're confident it's good, push staging to production

Comment: A typical configuration will have three environments, dev, staging and production.  dev is local and often for each developer.  staging is a production-like environment, perhaps even available on the internet for full-site testing, but not hooked up to the production domain or ports and with perhaps some restricted access (to beta testers or in-house testers).  Production is what you would expect.  You do initial testing on dev, then deploy full builds to staging for full-system testing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Develop the new version of the application
2. Keep a second copy of the prod droplet using the snapshot functionality
3. Deploy the new version to this copy server
4. Test it out
5. If you are happy with the changes - update the real server with your new version

You can get fancy with blue/greens, canaries, and % traffic here.

If you need more help lmk and we can setup some time outside of SO